# How to pass data from one activity to another using MVP pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-mvp

I have a `Recyclerview` in `MainActivity` where data are from an API. I want to open a `DetailsActivity` after clicking an item.

Now in *MVP* pattern, how should I pass the data object from `MainActivity` to `DetailsActivity`? I used *Interactor* in `Mainactivity` to handle data part.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with your data. You could write it to a Repository of some sort, and then have your Presenter retrieve it when the View is attached.

Answer (score 1):

Under an assumption `DetailsActivity` is supposed to show "details" that have `id`, you may pass the `id` through a `Bundle` to `DetailsActivity` and fetch "details" by the `id`.

If the assumption is wrong, then you might make the "details" [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) and pass them through a `Bundle` to the `DetailsActivity`.

By using either of the approaches it is guaranteed that the data passed through a `Bundle` will "survive" a process death in case your app process is killed by the system in background. I.e., when navigating back to the app the `Bundle` will be "redelivered" to `DetailsActivity`.

> I can directly pass the data to the `DetailActivity` through *Intent*, but how is the *MVP* approach here?

In *MVP*, a view (*V*) is usually platform specific, so it's fine for it (in *Android*) to operate with `Bundle`.

> That means I can directly send data to `DetailActivity`?

Yes, it might be as follows. *Presenter* (P) of `DetailsActivity` gets an `id` passed via *Intent* and "asks" *Interactor* to get the details data from *Repository* (or some other abstraction you use).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `callback` in your `adapter` and pass data from your `adapter` to

your first `activity` then pass data from first `activity` to second `activity` with `Parcelable`.

You can follow this for use `Parcelable`.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable